# Looking for lyrics of a soundtrack from the movie A Clockwork Orange

Tags: lyrics, soundtrack

I am looking for the lyrics to "Ode to Joy". A recording is at this link: https://m.soundcloud.com/user394434059/05-march-from-a-clockwork-orange-ninth-symphony-fourth-movement-abridged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Beethoven's Symphony No. 9, Fourth Movement - *An Die Freude* ("Ode to Joy")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symphony_No._9_%28Beethoven%29#Fourth_movement).
Full lyrics and English translation are on the Wikipedia page linked above. The lyrics, which are in German, are from a poem by Friedrich Schiller.

Here's a video with lyrics and English translation following the symphonic version:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4pbMUEHvoAo

---

This track and much of the synthesizer music on that soundtrack was arranged and performed by [Wendy Carlos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wendy_Carlos), who is probably best known for "[Switched-On Bach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched-On_Bach#Influence)".  She went on to work with Kubrick again, composing much of the soundtrack for "The Shining".

Comment: guy you can not even imagine how a big favor you did.. thank you very much

Comment: Wendy Carlos' performance is probably the human voice processed through a vocoder modulating the tones of Carlos' synthesizers, with the timbre and lyrics deliberately obscured for effect.

Comment: Wendy Carlos is famous for not permitting any of her recordings to be made available on YouTube, for streaming online, or for sale as digital downloads. Some people have attempted to post her recordings on YouTube or Soundcloud, but as soon as she identifies them, she has them taken down for copyright violation. YouTube clips that people have uploaded have been replaced by YouTube with generic public domain orchestral music. This SoundCloud clip you have found will probably be deleted quickly as a result.

Comment: I would add that the soundtrack album for A Clockwork Orange is long out-of-print as a CD or as vinyl; your only chance of purchasing it is to find a used copy for sale in a used record store.

Comment: Carlos also released an album of music composed for the film that ended up not being used in the film itself, called *Walter Carlos' Clockwork Orange*, on vinyl in 1972. That is also long out of print. There was a very limited re-release on CD (using the name Wendy and not Walter) in 1998, which is likewise long out of print. Several used record dealers on Amazon offer used copies they are selling for between US $36 and $80. The complete title of the re-release is *A Clockwork Orange: Wendy Carlos' Complete Original Score*.

Comment: The human vocals for the track were provided by [Rachel Elkind](http://www.wendycarlos.com/rachel.html).  Great info, thanks!  Guess I scored on that LP - 99 cents at the thrift store.